# Scala - How to concat values from multiple keys in a map

Tags: scala, functional-programming, yield

I want to write a function that takes a `List[String]`and a `Map[String,List[Int]]`.
I want to iterate over the list of String and get the values if the key exists in the Map.
I already have this:

```
def getIntList(search_keys: List[String], mapped: Map[String, List[Int]]): List[Int] =
    for ((k:String,v:List[Int]) <- mapped if search_keys.contains(k)) yield {
      v
    }
```

This function does not return a `List[Int]` as intended but `Iterable[List[Int]]`.
I already tried to flatten after the for-loop but that didn't work.
I think I'm having trouble understanding what is returned in the loop. Maybe there is a better way to do this?
Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `l.flatMap(m.get).flatten`, for example

```
val l = List("a", "c")
val m = Map("a" -> List(1,2), "b" -> List(3,4), "c" -> List(5,6))

l.flatMap(m.get).flatten
// res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 5, 6)
```

where `m.get` returns `Option[List[Int]]` so we in effect have to flatten twice to get at `Int`s

Comment: Wow thats so much more simple than my attempt. I think I should look into flatMap again. Also one more question. Is it possible with this attempt to also filter for values that exist for all the keys?

Comment: Also, you can try `l.flatMap(k => m.getOrElse(k, default = List.empty))`